# How to Change the Web Application url for an existing webapp?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Some information about our SharePoint system:

I have 3 server for serving this Sharepoint

ServerA: Sharepoint foundation 2013 version 15.0.4569.1506
ServerB: SQL server 2012 developer
ServerC: OWA

I've follow these step to change URL:
1. Extend the Web application.
2. Add new url in Host header.
3. Once done creating Modify your AAM settings and add the new url as default.

Unfortunately, all the existing documents like word, excel, pptx cannot open. Can anyone advice me?

**Event logs show:**

> Event code: 3005  Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
>   Event time: 9/12/2017 12:44:56 PM  Event time (UTC): 9/12/2017 5:44:56
>   AM  Event ID: c29ceb228ce74020b17e9df21f746d4c  Event sequence: 4 
>   Event occurrence: 1  Event detail code: 0    Application information: 
>       Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/x-1-131496686927702427 
>       Trust level: Full 
>       Application Virtual Path: /x 
>       Application Path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Web Apps\ExcelServicesWfe\ 
>       Machine name: OWA2013    Process information: 
>       Process ID: 3052 
>       Process name: w3wp.exe 
>       Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE    Exception information: 
>       Exception type: ExcelWebRendererException 
>       Exception message: We couldn't find the file you wanted.    at Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI.EwaState.OpenWorkbook()    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI.ExcelWebRendererInternal.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)    at
>   ASP._layouts_xlviewerinternal_aspx.__Render__control6(HtmlTextWriter
>   __w, Control parameterContainer)    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)    at
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)    at
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)    at
>   ASP._layouts_xlviewerinternal_aspx.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter
>   __w, Control parameterContainer)    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)    at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   We couldn't find the file you wanted.    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI.EwaState.EnsureDocumentHostInfo()    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI.EwaState.OpenWorkbook()    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.ServiceHost.ServiceHostLoader.GetCheckedBaseDocument(String
>   querySignature, BaseUser baseUser, String canary, Boolean
>   shouldCheckCanary, ScenarioRestrictions restriction)    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.ServiceHost.ServiceHost.GetCheckedBaseDocument(String
>   uri, String canary, Boolean shouldValidateCanary, Byte[]
>   documentProperties, ScenarioRestrictions restriction)    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.ServiceHost.ServiceHost.Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.Host.IEwaHost.GetDocumentHostInfo(String
>   uri, String canary, Boolean shouldValidateCanary, Byte[]
>   documentProperties, Boolean isGenerated, ScenarioRestrictions
>   restriction, ResourceThrottlingScenario scenario)    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI.EwaState.EnsureDocumentHostInfo() WOPI
>   Check File    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Common.WopiDocument.CheckWopiFile()    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.ServiceHost.ServiceHostLoader.GetCheckedBaseDocument(String
>   querySignature, BaseUser baseUser, String canary, Boolean
>   shouldCheckCanary, ScenarioRestrictions restriction)
>       Request information: 
>       Request URL: http://owa.example.com/x/_layouts/xlviewerinternal.aspx?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&WOPISrc=http://example.com:8080/_vti_bin/wopi.ashx/files/9e13adc35b634a21b1c89f7d402a3dc8&sc=http://example.com:8080/SitePages/Home.aspx&wdEnableRoaming=1
>
> ```
> Request path: /x/_layouts/xlviewerinternal.aspx 
> User host address: xx.xx.xx.xx 
> User:  
> Is authenticated: False 
> Authentication Type:  
> Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE    Thread information: 
> Thread ID: 7 
> Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
> Is impersonating: False 
> Stack trace:    at Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI.EwaState.OpenWorkbook()    at
> ```
>
> Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI.ExcelWebRendererInternal.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)    at
>   ASP._layouts_xlviewerinternal_aspx.__Render__control6(HtmlTextWriter
>   __w, Control parameterContainer)    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)    at
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)    at
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)    at
>   ASP._layouts_xlviewerinternal_aspx.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter
>   __w, Control parameterContainer)    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)    at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

---

I've tried another way to change url, these is the steps:

- Currently, Alternate access mappings is:
  [image]

notes: http://spf2013 <= this is SharePoint server name.
http://spf.xxx.com <= this is public url so user at home can access.

- I've created a excel file named TEST_1, it can access at the moment.
  [image]
- I changed the http://spf2013 to http://spf.xxx.com and set it default zone.
  [image]

[image]

- After that I've tried access to TEST_1 but it shows me error below.
  [image]
- I did IISREST for both SP and OWA server but nothing change, the error still there.
- Every sites collection can access normally except all documents.

P/S: The reason why I need to change the url since I set alert notification for task, documents... the alert email using the Default Zone URL to send notification so user cannot access at home.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved it by my self by adding this line to both SharePoint and OWA server in hosts file. C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

> xx.xx.xx.xx spf.xxx.com

***Related issue***: if your SharePoint enable search feature please look into this also:

> *Search feature cannot crawl since it is prevents access to a web application with a fully qualified domain name to from the host
>   server.*

**Workaround:**

Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.

> · In Registry Editor, locate and then click the following registry
>   key:
>
> · HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa
>
> · Right-click Lsa, point to New, and then click DWORD(32-bit) Value.
>
> · Type DisableLoopbackCheck, and then press ENTER.
>
> · Right-click DisableLoopbackCheck, and then click Modify.
>
> · In the Value data box, type 1, and then click OK.
>
> · Quit Registry Editor, and then restart your computer.
>
> . Manual re-crawl then search will work normally.

Answer (score 0):

Could you access the site collection successfully using the extended host header URL?
Did you have any other issues when you access the site collection using the host header url?

You said adding new url in Host Header, in the host header, you should add a valid host name in Host header.

Comment: access to site collection normally and no have any issue. I did change url to other url so office web app cannot find the existing files.